# Quoting parameter in read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, quoting

what is the exact use of quoting parameter in pandas.read_csv()? I checked the documentation, but I can't comprehend it.

```
df = pd.read_csv("labeledTrainData.tsv", header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3)
```

Comment: I've mostly used it with `quoting=3` when the underlying data is problematic and has an unbalanced quote somewhere. This typically causes a catastrophic and cryptic parsing error at some point, saying that an EoF character was encountered on some line, though the real issue was an unbalanced quote several thousand lines above.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with how to interpret quoted fields in the file you are reading.  They are defined in the csv module.

> csv.QUOTE_ALL Instructs writer objects to quote all fields.
>
> csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields
>   which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any
>   of the characters in lineterminator.
>
> csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC Instructs writer objects to quote all non-numeric
>   fields.
>
> Instructs the reader to convert all non-quoted fields to type float.
>
> csv.QUOTE_NONE Instructs writer objects to never quote fields. When
>   the current delimiter occurs in output data it is preceded by the
>   current escapechar character. If escapechar is not set, the writer
>   will raise Error if any characters that require escaping are
>   encountered.

It defaults to minimaL and can very often be kept there.  However if you did use one of the other to write the csv, you should use it when reading too.